Does the default CloudFront metrics include viewer request headers? If not is it possible to create a metric for that?
I am trying to record the number of requests received by my Cloudfront distribution by viewer request host headers. I don't need super granular data (aggregated by the day is fine), but it does need to be scalable at a reasonable price. If it's not possible with Cloudwatch metrics is there another way? Thanks for the help!
The documentation says there is a default Cloudwatch metric "Requests" that is "The total number of viewer requests received by CloudFront, for all HTTP methods and for both HTTP and HTTPS requests." This does not seem to include info on host headers. Is there another metric, or can I create such a metric?
